# Intervals and Signs

Tags: calculus

In the first and second derivative tests, I find whether the derivative is positive or negative by picking a random number within that open interval. The number I pick is arbitrary; however, what guarantees that the random number I pick from that interval is representative of the entire interval?

For example, with $$f'(x)=6x-12$$
I get the intervals $$(-\infty, 2)$$ and $$(2, \infty)$$

From the first interval I get a negative sign, and from the second interval I get a positive sign. I figured this out by computing particular values within the interval, but how do I know that because one particular number came out with some sign, all the numbers in that interval will come out with that sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way a continuous function can go from positive to negative, or vice versa, is by passing through zero.

Thus, once you've found all the points where your function is either zero or discontinuous, you'll know that it cannot change sign anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the value of $f'(x)$ where to change in the interval $(2,\infty)$. For example $f'(3)=6$, and suppose $f(a)<0$ for some $a>3$. The Intermediate Value Theorem states that $f'(b)=0$ for some $3<b<a$, but the only zero of $f'(x)$ is $2$.

Comment: This example helped a lot, thanks!